# How to convert a ArrayList into a Map using Java8?

Tags: java-8

I have the below requirement and I want to use Java-8 to meet the desired solution:

Input ->

```
ArrayList<String> places = new ArrayList<String>(
    Arrays.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata", "Paris"));
```

Output-> `HashMap<String,List<String>> detailsMap=new HashMap<>();`

```
{"Buenos Aires"=[ "Córdoba", "La Plata", "Paris"], "Córdoba"=["Buenos Aires", "La Plata", "Paris"],

"La Plata"=["Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "Paris"], "Paris"=["Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata"]}
```

How I can achieve this using Java-8?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to achieve that using streams.

```
List<String> places =  Arrays.asList("Buenos Aires", "Córdoba", "La Plata", "Paris");

Map<String, List<String>> map = places.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), e-> places.stream().filter(k -> !e.equals(k)).collect(Collectors.toList())));
```